# Sustainable hunting in South-East Asia

Tags: southeast-asia, ethical-travel, hunting

One of my buddies asked me a question and I don't have an answer for him. So, I thought I would run it by here.

He is a big hunter. As in, he travels for hunting... a lot. However, he tries to be ethical about it. He wants to know if there is any hunting in South-East Asia that is sustainable, as is it doesn't damage the environment.

I know there is government legalized hunting in several countries in SE Asia, but that doesn't necessarily make it sustainable. Anyone know of a program in SE Asia that fits?

I've looked in hunting forums, but for the most part it just seems a bunch of guys who like to go around shooting stuff. They pretty much just consider the legality of it.

**Edit:** Countries such as Indonesia, Malaysia, Papau, Timor, Philippines.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific with countries they're looking at visiting? For example I have info on hunting in Kyrgyzstan, although I'd consider it more Central Asia, but they may not...

Comment: @Mark Sure, I would consider Kyrgyzstan Center as well, but I'll edit it.

Comment: Ah, worth doing, as I initially assumed Thailand, Cambodia etc.  OK, will look into those ones.

Comment: What kind of hunting specifically? As in what kind of game? Small/Med/large/Dangerous?

Comment: @Kaushik Really any. Birds and large being his favorite though. However, as he says, every different type is a different challenge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Indonesia, we hunt wild boar since it's considered as a pest to our padi field.

If you interested you can contact Perbakin(Indonesian Shooting Association) Medan that holds Hunting Safari regularly, to control the wild boar population.

Here is the name and the address :

1. Sekretariat Pengda Perbakin Sumatera Utara

   Jl Sei Deli 14-16 Medan
   Telp number +62-61-4524579
2. PB PERBAKIN ( in Jakarta, Indonesian Capital )

   Lapangan Tembak Bung Karno Jl Gelora Senayan - Jakarta Pusat 10270
   Phone +62-21-5737128 / +62-21-5739473

[image]

Answer (score 5):

One example in Papua New Guinea of sustainable hunting is the Tree Kangaroo.  Not exactly big game, but it's different, and fits how the locals look after their environment and culture.

For information, take a look at this [link](http://conservationconnections.blogspot.com/2011/04/sustainable-hunting-success-story.html).